# How to ask if someone has finished eating (their food/meal)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, food

How can I correctly say that I have eaten all my food (the food is gone)?
How can I correctly ask someone if he has eaten all his food?

Imagine the situation when your child is eating:

Does the following dialogue sound fine?

> - Have you eaten your food?  (I want to know if my son has finished eating and has eaten all his food)
> - Yes, I have eaten my food!
> - Good boy!

Comment: OK, there's two things going on here that are a bit at war.  Someone may be "finished eating" before the "food is gone".  I'd recommend: "Have you eaten all of your food?" If you're trying to ask your son if his plate is empty.

Comment: Thank you. Is the phrase "Have you eaten your food ?" in the same context completely incorrect ? Or it is good but not very good

Comment: My grandmother always asked if I had a "happy plate" (one with no food left on it)

Comment: @chumakoff, that sentence is grammatically correct but the usage is wrong. That (your) sentence is asking if you've eaten your food (known already finished eating), but asking _"Have you finished eating your food?"_ would be asking if you've completed eating the food (may not finished eating yet, unknown). **Disclaimer:** _Explained in the simplest form._

Comment: By *the food is over*, I think you mean either *the food is gone* or *the meal is over*, or possibly *the food/meal is finished*. But *the food is over* is not natural English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds fine to me. Good ear, that's exactly how I would say it! You could also say

- Have you eaten *all* your food?
- Have you *finished* your food?
- Have you *finished all* your food?

but your first sentence is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

The options in DC's are fine. In addition, however, you do not have to use the present perfect (at least in American English).

Are you done/finished with your food?

Are you done/finished with your meal?

Are you finished with your plate?

Are you done/finished eating?

Comment: Which of your examples mean that the food should be gone ?

Comment: @chumakoff If a person is eating, and he eats all the food on his plate, and you can see that all the food is gone... Why would you ask the person if they have finished/eaten all their food? You know they have, because you can see that the food is gone.

Comment: I am agree with you. But, if I want to pay attention in my question that the food should be all gone, then what will be the best way to ask my question ?

Comment: The questions in the answer by @DJMcMayhem are all good.